# How does Apple identify that my app supports iPhone 6 and 6+?

Tags: ios, iphone-6

How does Apple identify that my app supports iPhone 6 and 6+?

I found something on [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html).

> IMPORTANT
>
> You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6.

So, are they identifying device support using **launch XIB** or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using an XIB file for your launch screen, Apple knows that you are supporting the iPhone 6 (+). If you only want to support iOS 8 devices you can stay with this only XIB file as your launch screen. If you want to support iOS 7 as well you need to have real pictures in each size for every device you want to support in you images.xcassets.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is even though it suggests that you DO need to use a launch file to support iPhone 6/Plus. You can still skip this and use launch images instead as indicated by the same article you are referring to.The iPhone 6 still uses the @2x resolution images while the 6 Plus uses the @3x resolution.

The launch file is just a normal XIB file, nothing special about it and it acts just like the rest of the XIB files in your project, it adjusts itself depending on the resolution of the iPhone it runs on.